# MongoDB nested queries problem: uncaught exception: SyntaxError: missing : after property id :

Tags: mongodb, subquery

[The document I'm using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXL9J.png)

Why doesn't work this query?
[my queris code doesn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxNeJ.png)

Please help!! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adresa.judet need to be in quotes like "adresa.judet"